# Comparing custom Geometry classes (Lines and Planes): How to increase the accuracy of the __eq__ method

Tags: python-3.x, classes

I'm creating custom classes to represent Planes and Lines on a 3d graph. To help improve the performance of my process I've started implementing `__eq__` so that I can eliminate duplicate objects in a list using `objList = set(objList)`.

I'm wondering how to efficiently expand the `__eq__` methods so that it can compare if the objects represent the same "geometry" on a graph? ie: Plane `0=ax+by+cz+d` should be marked as equal to `0=2ax+2by+2cz+2d`

For the planes class I've added two version but I'm worried that my second version isn't proper since the hashes of both objects won't be same and or that precision issues might reject objects that are equal.

ie: [conceptual not actual example] `6/3 = 2.0000000001` instead of `2/1 = 2`

Note: I include both classes (Plane and Line) in this post because even if the algebra is different between the two classes, I assume that the main idea of how to approach this problem will be the same between both classes.

```
class Plane_v1:
    '''
    0 = ax + by + cz + d
    '''
    a = None
    b = None
    c = None
    d = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Plane\n\ta :{self.a}\tb :{self.b}\tc :{self.c} \n\td: {self.d}"

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d))

    def __eq__(self, value):
        if value is None: return False
        return self.a == value.a and self.b == value.b and self.c == value.c and self.d == value.d 

class Plane_v2:
    '''
    0 = ax + by + cz + d
    '''
    a = None
    b = None
    c = None
    d = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Plane\n\ta :{self.a}\tb :{self.b}\tc :{self.c} \n\td: {self.d}"

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d))

    def __eq__(self, value):
        if value is None: return False
        if self.d == 0 or value.d == 0:
            return self.a == value.a and self.b == value.b and self.c == value.c and self.d == value.d
        return self.a/self.d == value.a/value.d and self.b/self.d == value.b/value.d and self.c/self.d == value.c/value.d

class Line:
    '''
    x = x0 + ta
    y = y0 + tb
    z = z0 + tc
    '''
    x0 = None
    y0 = None
    z0 = None
    a = None
    b = None
    c = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Line\n\tx0:{self.x0}\ty0:{self.y0}\tz0:{self.z0} \n \ta :{self.a}\tb :{self.b}\tc :{self.c}"
        return super().__str__()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b, self.c, self.x0, self.y0, self.z0))

    def __eq__(self, value):
        if value is None: return False
        return self.a == value.a and self.b == value.b and self.c == value.c and self.x0 == value.x0 and self.y0 == value.y0 and self.z0 == value.z0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple of things you can do:

1. Include an `__init__` function. Since the `Plane` class isn't very complex or dynamic, this is best acheived using a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (Note: `dataclasses` where introduced in python3.7).
2. Make the class immutable, which provides stronger hash guarantees (otherwise it would be possible for an object in a set to be mutated, resulting in an incorrect state for the set). We can make the class immutable by passing the `frozen=True` parameter to the `dataclass` decorator.
3. The `__eq__` method works as intended, but the `__hash__` function does not. For example, `0 = 1x + 2y + 3z + 10` and `0 = 2x + 4y + 6z - 123` would be equal but would *not* have the same hash (we want them to have the same hash). To achieve this, we can use the unit vectors `[a, b, c]` since the unit vectors for both equations will be the same if the two planes have the same geometry.  The unit vectors can be used for both `__eq__` and `__hash__`.
4. To avoid float point precision errors, we can make use of python's [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) or [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) libraries.

Here's the full code which implements the above changes:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from fractions import Fraction

def compute_unit_vector(vector: tuple) -> tuple:
    total = sum(map(abs, vector))

    # if total = 0, that means the vector is a zero vector, which will cause
    # a division by zero error when calculating the unit vector, so we explicitly
    # check this case here
    if total == 0: 
        return vector 

    # we use Fraction here to prevent float point precision errors
    return tuple(Fraction(x, total) for x in vector)
    

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Plane:
    """0 = ax + by + cz + d"""

    a: float
    b: float
    c: float
    d: float

    @property
    def unit_vector(self):
        return compute_unit_vector((self.a, self.b, self.c))
    
    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self.unit_vector)

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        return self.unit_vector == other.unit_vector
```

Here's an example using a set:

```py
set([Plane(1, 2, 3, 4), Plane(2, 4, 6, 8), Plane(0, 0, 0, 0), Plane(-2, -4, -6, -8)])
```

Which results in the set:

```py
{Plane(a=-2, b=-4, c=-6, d=-8),
 Plane(a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0),
 Plane(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)}
```

**Edit:** We can make things a bit faster if we initialize `self.unit_vector` in `__post_init__` instead of as an `@property` method, since `@property` will recalculate every time it is called:

```py
    # replace the @property def unit_vector method with this instead
    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        # this is a hack, we can't do self.unit_vector = unit_vector
        # because the object is immutable via frozen=True
        unit_vector = compute_unit_vector((self.a, self.b, self.c))
        object.__setattr__(self, 'unit_vector', unit_vector)
```